# How is French written in telegraphy and other settings in which diacritics are not possible?

Tags: orthography, french, diacritics

The French alphabet has 5 diacritics and 2 orthographic ligatures, to make 16 extra letters. In Latin scripts, letters with diacritics like ä, å or à, ñ, ö, and ü can be transcribed as ae, aa, gn, oe, and ue.

However, in telegraphy, there are no codes for Ââ, Êê, Ëë, Îî, Ïï, Ôô, Ùù, Ûû, Ÿÿ in Continental Morse. In Telex, all letters with diacritics including **Çç, Èè** are totally gone but in European variant of original Baudot code where only Éé existed.

Can modern French do without diacritic, or only with Éé at most, in telecommunication especially?

Comment: Curious... Is <ñ> actually transcribed as <gn>? I know the latter represent the same sound in French and Italian as the former does in Spanish, but I'd have guessed Spanish speakers would not in general see it as a straightforward replacement.

Comment: @LjL Ñ is the shorthand of nn (as in old Spanish), which nh, ny, nh and gn in other languages sound like.

Comment: @Schezuk I know that, but that wasn't my question. My question was whether it's common *in Spanish* to transcribe <ñ> as <gn> when the former is not available (such as in telegraphy as mentioned by the OP). I have a feeling it's not actually common. Colloquially on the internet, in my experience, Spanish speakers write <n> when <ñ> is not available.

Comment: @LjL, The transcription was an Italian proposal to the 1890 International Telegraph Conference in Paris, which was declined by a Spanish delegate. Ñ's mnemonic in Morse code was assigned as TY.

Comment: ha, that explains it given Italian orthography! I'm not too surprised that the Spanish iñored it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no common conventions in French for replacing letters with diacritics by digraphs.  In contexts where the diacritics are not available, the usage is just to omit them.  This is still common on uppercase letters, and was very common in the early days of Internet when programs were not 8-bit clean and accented letters were causing problems.

The result is usually understandable, but cases for which ambiguities arise are known (*DUPOND-MORETTI A LA BARRE* is a case which happened and is really better with an accent although there is little risk of misunderstanding, at least for those who know who Dupond-Moretti is; *UN INTERNE TUE* didn't, as far as I know, occur in the wild but it is impossible to choose between the four possibilities without the context).

Comment: It's important to note that if the sender is aware that there is no diacritics, they see and try to avoid ambiguities by rephrasing. I don't think anyone would write a telegraph with "UN INTERNE TUE" and think it will be understood unambiguously. So in practice it's pretty rare to have real ambiguity problems because of the absence of accents.

Comment: There have also been imfamous (or possibly apocryphal) cases of telegrams whose meaning changed critically due to omission of a comma.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely, jst lke Englsh cn wrk jst fne wth all the vwls in the mddle of wrds rmvd cmpltly. If you're a native English-speaker, you probably read that sentence without much difficulty, even though I removed a whole bunch of information from it.

Languages, as a rule, include a whole lot of redundancy. Speaking is a pretty noisy channel, and a lot of information can get lost. So spoken language has evolved to compensate, and written language gets those benefits as a useful side effect. Sometimes written language ends up with even more redundancy for historical reasons; this happened in both French and English (e.g. writing lets us distinguish "bare" from "bear", while speech doesn't).

In French, diacritics do carry information—*a* "has" (from *avoir*) vs *à* "to", *du* "of" vs *dû* "had to do it" (from *devoir*), *ca* "approximately" (abbreviation of *circa*) vs *ça* "it". If you remove those diacritics, you lose that information. But there's enough redundancy that you can almost always make do without them, and you can add even more if necessary: if confusion between *ca* and *ça* is causing problems, you can use *circa* and *ce* instead. This is what's happening when pilots say "affirmative" and "negative" instead of "yes" and "no"—it adds more redundancy, since radio is an even noisier channel than normal speech, and confusing the two could be disastrous.

Comment: Cn y rd ths? D y wnt t lrn Hbrw? Hbrw s wrttn wtht mst vwls. T's fn n hlps bld brn clls.

Comment: I can read it, and I don't even need to be a native speaker like Draconis seems to require! And honestly most of my brain cells are fried, so it must be pretty easy.

Comment: @LjL Entirely valid! I just wanted to hedge slightly in case OP is a non-native speaker who runs into trouble with my example.

Comment: m t. bt thn gn, y s, n r l s nt snk.
we could spawn a new area51 puzzling site from this. or does it exist already?

Comment: @dlatikay I must declare defeat at n r l s.

Answer (score 3):

French with accents and diacritics is confortable to read, as it provides all necessary information. "Bare" French requires some guesswork.
Middle French used not to have accents, but there was quite a lot of mute consonants, that were used to clarify neighboring vowels.